# Question regarding a proof of the chain rule.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation, chain-rule

[image]

---

One can derive $(5)$ by letting $$v(s)=\frac{g(s)-g(y)}{s-y}-g'(y)$$

for $s\neq y$. The problem I have is in letting $s=f(t)$. It is not obvious to me that the expression still holds, particularly because $s-y=f(t)-y$  might equal $0$ and there is no guarantee that the expression is well defined around $y=f(x)$.

Comment: If $s = y$ then $g(s) - g(y) = (s - y)[g'(y) + v(s)] = 0.$ What expression in the proof is not well defined around $y=f(x)$?

Comment: If $s=y$ then I don't see why $v(s)$ would be defined.

Comment: So don't define it by your equation. I don't see where the proof used that method.

Comment: Check what definition of differentiability your book uses. It probably doesn't have division in it.

Comment: It does. It's the usual quotient definition.

Comment: And I see what you mean David, although how could one show that such a $v(s)$ exists then to begin with?

Comment: Okay, then I think you have to extend $v(s)$ by continuity at point $s=y$ to be $v(y) = 0$

Comment: Oh, that seems to work. Thanks.